# Separating relationship types by | (pipe) vs |: (pipe colon)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The [Neo4j MATCH documentation says](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-match.html#match-match-by-multiple-relationship-types) that

> To match on one of multiple types, you can specify this by chaining them together with the pipe symbol `|`

but gives an example where the separator used is in fact `|:`, not just `|`

> ```
> MATCH (wallstreet { title:'Wall Street' })<-[:ACTED_IN|:DIRECTED]-(person)
> RETURN person
> ```

Experimenting in my local Neo4j browser, it seems that the two separators (`|` and `|:`) behave identically; that is, the query

```
MATCH (wallstreet { title:'Wall Street' })<-[:ACTED_IN|DIRECTED]-(person)
RETURN person
```

seems to do the same thing as the one from the Neo4j docs, at least on my data set. But this invites the question of why Neo4j would implement two similar syntaxes to do exactly the same thing.

Are the behaviours of the two syntaxes above in fact identical, or is there a subtle difference between them that doesn't show up on my data set? Whatever the answer may be, is it documented anywhere? And if there is no difference between them, what is the rationale for Cypher supporting both syntaxes?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK - there are no differences.

Rationality - backward compatibility.

Over time, Cypher language has been evolved. 
If I recall correctly, there were ~3 implementations of Cypher language.

So, to allow users to migrate to new Neo4j versions, without rewriting all queries, Cypher retained old syntax support.

For example, in the past (< 3.0.0) you were able to use "bare node" syntax:

```
node-[rel]-otherNode
```

General recommendation - do not use deprecated syntax.
If the syntax is not mentioned in documentation explicitly - it can be considered as deprecated.

Deprecations page in documentation - http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/deprecations.html

Comment: Given that the documentation describes one syntax but actually demonstrates the other, I wouldn't interpret either as deprecated.

Comment: The separator is `|`. And relationship type is `:TYPE`. So, chaining all together will result in something like `:TYPE1|:TYPE2|:TYPE3`. It looks more logical, especially when you think about `|` as `OR` operator (like in many programming languages).